# ASP.NET MVC 3: Integrating with the jQuery UI date picker

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui, razor

Im using this guide by Stuart Leeks: [ASP.NET MVC 3: Integrating with the jQuery UI date picker and adding a jQuery validate date range validator](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stuartleeks/archive/2011/01/25/asp-net-mvc-3-integrating-with-the-jquery-ui-date-picker-and-adding-a-jquery-validate-date-range-validator.aspx)

I get this "weird" error: "The model item passed into the dictionary is null, but this dictionary requires a non-null model item of type 'System.DateTime'." 
...in my create.cshtml view.

Im using a little bit different approach since I am only (for the moment) interested in getting the actual plugin to work. And also I want to be able to use the datepicker when I Create an item.

my "Speaker.cs" model:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DefaultValue("00-00-00")]   <- thought this might fix the "not null error", with no succes..
public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set;  }
```

added a partial view "Date.cshtml" under the "views/Speaker"EditorTemplates" folder.

```
@model DateTime
@Html.TextBox("", Model.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), new { @class = "date" })
```

my create.cshtml view

```
@model HiFiWarehouse.Models.Speaker
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
```

added a "EditorHookup.js" in scripts folder

```
/// <reference path="jquery-1.5.1.js" />
/// <reference path="jquery-ui-1.8.11.js" />

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".date").datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy" });
});
```

create actions in controller

```
//
// GET: /Speaker/Create
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrators") 
public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View();
} 

//
// POST: /Speaker/Create

[HttpPost]
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrators")]
public ActionResult Create(Speaker speaker)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Speakers.Add(speaker);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");  
    }

    return View(speaker);
}
```

my _Layout.cshtml header:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/EditorHookup.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

what am I doing wrong here? :)

Answer (score 2):

It is telling you that you need to make your ReleaseDate a nullable type:

```
public DateTime? ReleaseDate { get; set;  }
```

The other problem is that DefaultValue of 00-00-00 will not work. As far as I am aware DateTime.MinValue is 0001-01-01.

Comment: it didnt fix the problem sorry :(

Comment: fixed it! you were nearly correct (ir I missunderstood). The problem was that my partial view didnt accept a null date. 

@model DateTime?